# Как добавить в title сайта emoji с помощью php в кодировке HTML Entity (Decimal)?

Tags: php, html, joomla, seo, unicode

Почему то не получается корректно реализовать возможность добавления в Title страниц сайта emoji в кодировке HTML Entity (Decimal). В коде страницы emoji не сохраняет кодировку. Пример: Кодировка - `&#128640;` = emoji - . Пишем вот `&#128640;` так, выводит `&amp;#128640;`. А должно выводится вот так `&#128640;` Может кто знает в чем проблема?

Comment: Очевидно, в том, что кто-то экранирует. Зачем вам entity, что мешает просто взять и добавить emoji в заголовке?

Answer (score 2):

Есть функция для перевода HTML-ENTITIES в текст. Попробуй так:

```
echo mb_convert_encoding('&#128640;', 'UTF-8', 'HTML-ENTITIES');
```

В браузере должно отразиться как:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> Rocket Emoji</title>
...
```

Comment: Наверное я немного не правильно выразился. В браузере должно быть вот так
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>&#128640; Rocket Emoji</title>
...

Comment: нет, в браузере в title должно быть `<title> Rocket Emoji</title>` иначе не сработает. хотя стой.. Вы хотите с амперсантом код вывести вместо самой эмоджи?

Comment: seo хотят что бы было <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>&#128640; Rocket Emoji</title ПРИМЕР https://pastenow.ru/34835028f459e513bf3d682693ca1fb6

Comment: "Вы хотите с амперсантом код вывести вместо самой эмоджи?"

ДА, именно так